# how to let phonegap send image to laravel

Tags: cordova, laravel

I am making a smartphone "app".

The costumer wants a mobile version of his laravel based website on his smartphone. 
But he wants an app in the app store.

My idea was to make a mobile version of his website with jquery mobile (ofcourse the same backend).
Then redirect to the mobile site in a phonegap webview. It looks you you've got an app, but acually you see the website's mobile version. I don't have to make two versions of the website. One for phonegap and one mobile users go to his site trough a browser.

The only problem is. In the future the owners wants to take pictures with the smartphone so they can be put on the website.

Is there a way to send the image from phonegap to the laravel website?
If i click the upload button laravel wants to upload a file from you're computer, but it has to come from the phone. Or from taking a picture.

Comment: have you checked [this](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer)

Comment: you can use FileTransfer API in phoneGap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Camera API](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.3.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#camera.getPicture) to open up the camera on the device and take a picture. If you look at the options for this API, you can choose to save the photo to the users' device and get the location of the saved image back. Then you could use the [File Transfer API](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.3.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer) to upload that captured image to a server somewhere, assuming that the laravel website has an API or rest interface for uploading photos.